# Eclipse-project issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I started a project in eclipse,

when I open the corresponding folder initially there was new issue, once I started making another set of classes they are now located in the bin folder as .class, and not in the src.

Does anyone know why this is due?

Thank you

Comment: *there was new issue*. what issue?

Comment: @runDOSrun I think the OP meant "no issue".

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: The `bin` folder is supposed to contain all the compiled `.class` files. Any `.java` files go in the `src` folder. That said, any files you create will be created in the folder you create them in. So you are in control of where they are.

Comment: yeah, I was always simply creating the new classes, in my source folder in eclipse. Why are the new ones only as .class in the bin, and not my source folder. i can see them in the source folder in eclipse but not in the corresponding folder in spotlight (mac)

Comment: Refresh your project in eclipse and see if these really exist. If it's shown you're most likely in the wrong workspace folder in spotlight.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a java project in eclipse, you will get the option where to specify your output folder. By default it is bin, where all your .class are stored and you can change that.

Hope that helps.